# How do I see my chats?

Tags: support, chat

I've now realized that I don't know how to access to my old chats.

How do I know if someone answered me in a chat? Because I don't get any notifications in the "inbox". Is there a way to see the list of all the chats I've taken part in?

Comment: You can go to a chat, and search for your screen name.

Comment: You say that you do not get notifications about chat messages. (Which seems weird to me - possibly a bug?) I wanted to ask whether you got no notification about [this reply to your message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/20352/2023/12/26).

Comment: @MartinSleziak I received the comment notification, but not the chat notification. I see the message but I can't reply

Comment: @MathAttack What do do you mean by "I can't reply"? If you mean that my username is not offered my username isn't offered in autocomplete, that's because I wasn't in that room for some time, and I am no longer [pingable there](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/pingable/20352). You should still be able to reply to the message. See also: [Does ping work in chat with no autocompletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226321) and [Does a direct reply to a message in chat create a notification, no matter what age the message is?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/287972)

Comment: If you want to test out osme chat feature - such as pinging somebody using `@username` - feel free to try it [in my chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/19138/martin-sleziaks-room). I visited that room recently and I am still [pingable in that room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/pingable/19138) in this way.

Answer (score 4):

When you [go to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/) (and you're logged-in), you can see your username in the top right corner. After clicking on your username, you can get to [your chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/576128/math-attack).

There are several things you can see there:

- The rooms where you're room owner.
- The rooms you're currently in. And the rooms you were frequently in. (See [this link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94146) for an explanation how these rooms are chosen).
- List of chat-replies to you and  list of the conversations you've bookmarked.
- By clicking on the word "recent" you can get to the list [of your recent messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/576128/math-attack?tab=recent). Manually changing the URL you can get to the [second page](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/576128/math-attack?tab=recent&page=2) by adding `&page=2`; similarly for more pages. (In your case, the second page is empty at the moment - if you post something more there, you'll see more messages. You can also see recent messages by other users, if you find them [from the users tab](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users).)

If you go to [some user's chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/576128/math-attack), there is also a possibility to [search among their messages](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?user=576128&q=context).

See also: [Is there some way to see all of a user's messages in a chat room?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/274106)